# Spring MVC JSON serialization with a null field

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to serialize some object to JSON in Spring MVC. I use this method:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(produces = "application/json")
public class SurveyAPIController {

    SurveyService surveyService;

    @Autowired
    public SurveyAPIController(SurveyService surveyService) {
        this.surveyService = surveyService;
    }

    //*****************************
    // GET
    //*****************************

    @RequestMapping(value = "/survey/{id}",produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
    @ResponseBody
    public Survey getSurvey(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        return surveyService.getSurvey(id);
    }
}
```

There is Set field in the Survey object. If that Set is null, the JSON cannot be created and I get this error:

```
HTTP 500 - The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
```

How can I solve this proble,?

Comment: Could you post the stack trace.

Comment: Post the Survey object, the Set should already have been initialised on object creation.